# android audiomgr standby gets called

Tags: android

I have some code which streams audio from a server. It seems to work as expected for exactly 90 seconds and thereafter stops with the following three lines in the logcat -

D/AudioHardwareMot( 1052): AudioMgr:AudioStreamOutMot::standby called
D/AudioHardwareMot( 1052): AudioMgr:Output 0xb538 entering standby
D/AudioHardwareMot( 1052): AudioMgr:Closing stereo device

Do you know why the AudioMgr would automatically call standby for no reason?

Comment: Anybody has solution for this. I am facing this problem on my motorola android phone. @Arunabh, did you find any solution to this?